# Setting Up An Internal Network

Tags: lan

apologies if this is a duplicate question and overly basic.

I have spent several hours wrestling with this however I do appreciate that the answer is likely already here, albeit in more technical language than I am currently able to penetrate, compounded by what appears to multiple approaches.

My goal is simply to be able to access my test web application, which works on my local machine, from other machines inside my Local Area Network.

EDIT: My test app is a super simple PHP file which connects to a MySQL database, retrieves and displays the results from a singleton SQL select.  Works on local machine.

I am just a beginner and so looking for a tutorial or basic instructions.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't said anything about how your test web app is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the internal IP of your PC which is hosting the website using the command **ifconfig** on terminal

It would be mostly like 192.168.1.112

If you access your localhost website through http:/localhost/wordpress , try using  http:/192.168.1.112/wordpress

All you have to do is replace localhost with your internal IP. This should give access to your local website from any PC in network provided ports are left as such.

I am assuming you have something like WordPress on a LAMP setup

Comment: MAGIC!  Thanks so much!   I am running a single page, which retrieves and displays data from MySQL - just a super simple test app to make sure everything is installed properly before I start developing - networking is new to me.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped.